# Requesting an advice on big data validation

Tags: python, scala, amazon-deequ

I'm a newbie on big data validation and processing. Having little understanding about datacompy, which I have used to compare two datasets (pandas). However I couldn't find any source that can do data validations, i.e. column validations on emails, non emails, null, currency and date/time formats with python

e.g. Validation required on below sample data:

```
Address
-------
AAA AAA AAA
BBBB B bbbb
CCC CCCCCCC
abc@dbv.com
dews@fggv.uk
ASAA asas dasd
```

The data set I got contains email addresses under 'Address' column and need to validate, whether emails present in 'Address' column. 'Emil' column need to validate vice versa.

Also I prefer to return rows of invalids in the result (similarly datcompy compare.report, which output entire rows of mismatched ones).

I have tried Deequ with scala and the validations successfully state if validation errors found. However it is difficult to figure out the exact rows with invalid data.

Appreciate if some one can guide me a reference, course or any other tool, language on this purpose. Preferred a solution on python or Deequ/scala.

Comment: please share more info about what you have tried so far. Some input and output samples will be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas gave me the solution as below

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep='\t')
x = data[data['Email'].str.match(r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)')]
```